# Non-existent keys in mutating maps vs similar in arrays

Tags: go

I'm a newbie in golang and this part of a tour of Go about [mutating maps](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/18) is killing my world of pink ponies.

Here is an example of the problem:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := make([]int, 10)
    fmt.Println(a[123]) //panic: runtime error: index out of range, good

    b := make(map[int]int, 10)
    fmt.Println(b[123]) // 0 ? WHAAAT? Not nil, not panic?
}
```

I know, that I can check element existence with second value, like this:

```
v, ok := b[11]
if (!ok) {
    // do something strange
}
```

But why I need to do this every time in every place where I need to get something from map? I consider maps like associative arrays, but this behavior is really strange.

How can I make a map with panic-level checking of keys?

Comment: You don't need to  "consider maps like associative arrays", they are hash maps and their behavior is well-defined.

Comment: I'm sure this is a FAQ somewhere… the "why" is simply because of the two sane options, returning the zero value or causing a panic, the former is far more useful in practice (e.g. `m[k]++` works even if `k` isn't yet in the map).

Comment: Dave, yes, I think, that this behavior can be used in some logic. But in same time, I sure, that it can make invisible mistakes with large amounts of data.

Comment: Go usually handles errors in normal control flow (`if err != nil`, etc.). Out-of-bounds access, nil pointer deref, and type assertion failure are the oddballs for panicking. In part, that's because those errors tend to indicate issues with program logic (off by one error setting bounds for a loop over an array, say), not only odd input (missing key in input JSON map, say). There're also issues with the other designs that would avoid panics (e.g., imagine the problems with unintentionally growing a slice by accessing `a[123]`).

Comment: That's not to say Go objectively did The Only Right Thing here (I don't like that kind of argument) but it might give useful context for understanding the decision and maybe even for how to better write in Go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to be certain that a zero value from a map isn't due to the key not existing is the "comma, ok" idiom (`v, ok := m[k]`).  If you need a panic response to a non-existent key, the best route is to write a helper function.

```
func mapSafe(m map[string]int, key string) (i int) {
    i, ok: = m[key]
    if (!ok) {
        panic("Key not in map")
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: I thought about some function like this one, but perspective of transferring it from package to package saddens me.

Comment: I don't see why you would regularly want panic in map access, though.  The "comma, ok" idiom allows for much cleaner error handling than a panic/recover pair.

Comment: Of course, I will use this way and will try to change my mind to go-way. =)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make a map with panic-level checking of keys?

You cannot.